# Textarea's and syllable counter. [JQuery/Javascript]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 text areas;

- Textarea #1 contains standard text,
- Textarea #2 contains the total syllable count

they work fine but they dis-align on line breaks.

I have a feeling the snippet of code here contains my issue;

```
    function $count_how_many_syllables($input) {
        $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").keyup(function () {
            var lines = $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").val().split(/\n/);
            var arrayOfLines = [];
            for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                arrayOfLines.push($.trim(lines[i]));
            }
            var $content;
            var $word = 0;
            var $syllable_count = "";
            var $result = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfLines.length; i++) {
                $content = arrayOfLines[i].toLowerCase();
                word = $content.replace(/(?:[^laeiouy]es|ed|[^laeiouy]e)$/, '')
                        .replace(/^y/, '')
                        .match(/[aeiouy]/g).length;
                if ($content.length < 1) {
                    $result = $result + "0\n"; 
                } else {
                    $syllable_count = word.toString();
                    $result = $result + $syllable_count + "\n";
                }
            }

            $("[name=set_" + $input + "_syllable_count]").val($result);
            // set scrolling
            $("[name=set_" + $input + "_syllable_count]").scrollTop = $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").scrollTop;
            $("[name=set_" + $input + "_syllable_count]").scrollLeft = $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").scrollLeft;
        });
    }

    setInterval(function ($) {
        $count_how_many_syllables("a");
    },100)(jQuery);
```

Here is a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tq3zzhna/ (type something and you'll see my issue)

Comment: not quite it's how you create `arrayOfLines` thats the problem

Comment: Okay so i swaped it out for, which should in turn record the line breaks into the array;

`var lines = $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").val().split(/\n/);
          var arrayOfLines = [];
    for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
     arrayOfLines.push($.trim(lines[i]));
    }`

Comment: I'm buildings something like this - maybe we could work together? contact me ajbraus[at]gmail.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the regex you are using to split the lines up. Because you are just finding each group of lines (i.e. non-line breaks), you are not taking empty lines with 0 characters into account. A better approach is to [`split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) by line breaks instead, so the empty lines are included:

This matches an optional carriage return and a line break:
`var arrayOfLines = $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").val().split(/\r?\n/);`

Another issue once that is fixed is that you are checking `$content.length < 3` which will include the empty lines. The fix to this is to only find the word count if `$content.length > 0`.

Lastly you can type words with no vowels which currently break the syllable match (`match()` returns null), so I added a bit of a hack to cope with it, you can probably do it better:

```
function $count_how_many_syllables($input) {
    $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").keyup(function () {

        // split into separate lines
        var arrayOfLines = $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").val().split(/\r?\n/);
        var $content;
        var $word = 0;
        var $syllable_count = "";
        var $result = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfLines.length; i++) {
            $content = arrayOfLines[i].toLowerCase();
            var word = $content.length;
            // if we have content, find the syllables
            if($content.length > 0) {
                word = ($content.replace(/(?:[^laeiouy]es|ed|[^laeiouy]e)$/, '')
                    .replace(/^y/, '')
                    .match(/[aeiouy]/g) || 'a').length; // handle word with no vowels
                if ($content.length <= 3) {
                    word = 1;
                }
            }

            if (word !== 0) {
                $syllable_count = word.toString();
                $result = $result + $syllable_count + "\n";
            } else {
                $result = $result + "0 \n";
            }
        }

        $("[name=set_" + $input + "_syllable_count]").val($result);
        // set scrolling
        $("[name=set_" + $input + "_syllable_count]").scrollTop = $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").scrollTop;
        $("[name=set_" + $input + "_syllable_count]").scrollLeft = $("[name=set_" + $input + "]").scrollLeft;
    });
}

(function ($) {
    $count_how_many_syllables("a");
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tq3zzhna/3/

Comment: Thanks that worked a charm! Thanks for point out the issues aswell, would of been at this for days.